# How to avoid parent toggling transition of a child with its own v-if (Vue)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a problem where a parent component triggers its child's transition, with its own v-if.

Here is a jsfiddle showing my problem. https://jsfiddle.net/rs106khc/7/

```
  <h>with replacement (not working as intended)</h>
  <button v-on:click="show1 = !show1">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <button v-on:click="showParentDiv1 = !showParentDiv1">
    parentToggle
  </button>
  <div v-if="!showParentDiv1">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="showParentDiv1">
    <transition name="fade">
      <p v-if="show1">hello</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
  
  
  <h>without replacement (working as intended)</h>
  <button v-on:click="show2 = !show2">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <button v-on:click="showParentDiv2 = !showParentDiv2">
    parentToggle
  </button>
  <div v-if="showParentDiv2">
    <transition name="fade">
      <p v-if="show2">hello</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
```

There are two sister elements of the same type and they are displayed using v-if, v-else. If then one of its childs has a transition that transition goes off if its parent gets undisplayed. It first attaches to its parent's sister and then activates the transition.

The solution I have found is to give the parent element an id and make the transition css dependent on it being a child of that id. But i'm not sure that is the correct solution.